# Problems with using fixup in multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I've been trying to get a table to look good. I've been using multirow, which is notoriously bad at vertical alignment. I want to use the fixup option (the -0.8in in the MWE below) to move where the "row spanning text" is. Problem is above a certain value for the fixup, it just seems to enlarge the top row and I have no idea why. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.cm,right=2.cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm]{geometry} % Make margins bigger

%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Obach results.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} \toprule
    Strategy & Details & Cost, \$ & Life expectancy, y & QALE, y & ICER, \$/DALY averted \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}[-0.8in]{1}& 2&7430 & 20.70 & 18.32& \(\cdots\) \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                        & 3 & 8190 & 20.67 & 18.22 & Dominated\\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                        &4 &9400& 20.40 & 17.34  & Dominated \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                        & No treatment & 9180 & 19.99  & 17.02 & Dominated \\ \cmidrule{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\label{Obach_results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with first row too large]

Comment: This doesn't use the fixup, but might work. `\multirow{4}{*}{\vspace{-1.2em}1}`

Comment: Perfect thanks. Still find the fixup bug odd but this works great so cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need such an adjustment: 0.56ex is enough:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.cm,right=2.cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm]{geometry} % Make margins bigger

%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Obach results.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} \toprule
    Strategy & Details & Cost, \$ & Life expectancy, y & QALE, y & ICER, \$/DALY averted \\ \midrule
& 2&7430 & 20.70 & 18.32& \(\cdots\) \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
 \multirow{2}{*}[-0.6ex]{1} & 3 & 8190 & 20.67 & 18.22 & Dominated\\ \cmidrule{2-6}
&4 &9400& 20.40 & 17.34 & Dominated \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
 & No treatment & 9180 & 19.99 & 17.02 & Dominated \\ \cmidrule{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\label{Obach_results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]